# How to change the tooltip description of the following control that control is from Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

In the following I show the tooltip that I want to change, the control shown is an upload (Ant Design) and I want to modify the tooltip

Thank you very much

```
const { Dragger } = Upload;

const props = {
  name: "file",
  multiple: true,
  action: "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76",
  onChange(info) {
    const { status } = info.file;
    if (status !== "uploading") {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }
    if (status === "done") {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
    } else if (status === "error") {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  }
};

return (
  <>
    <Dragger {...props}>
      <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
        <InboxOutlined />
      </p>
      <p className="ant-upload-text">
        Haga clic o arrastre el archivo a esta área para cargar
      </p>
      <p className="ant-upload-hint">
        Soporte para una carga única o masiva.
      </p>
    </Dragger>
    <Button type="primary" style={{ marginTop: 16 }}>
      Iniciar Carga
    </Button>
  </>
);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example React component?

Comment: Can you show some example code?

Comment: Yes, is here !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only way without editing their source code is using `ConfigProvider` to match your localization. I assume that's what you want to modify is convert the text to Spanish.

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/upload-by-clicking-antd4122-forked-nfy8d?file=/index.js)

Comment: It cannot, the two tooltips appear

Comment: @dany952 Looks like you're right. Please see my edits.

Comment: Thanks for this solution if it worked for me to change the language